# Porque document.getElementById('valor').value não funciona no RGraph?

Tags: javascript, html5, rgraph

```js
// Classe para chamar o Json.
function json() {
  var qtd;
  var retorno;

  // Resgatar valores.
  json.prototype.resgatarValores = function() {
    $('#resultado').html('Carregando dados...');

    // Estrutura de resultado.
    $.getJSON('/webpro/webadm/lncidjson', function(data) {
      this.qtd = data.usuarios.length - 1;
      this.valore = '';
      this.label = '';

      for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++) {
        if (i == (this.qtd - 1)) {
          this.valore += data.usuarios[i].valor;
          this.label += data.usuarios[i].descr;
        } else {
          this.valore += data.usuarios[i].valor + ',';
          this.label += data.usuarios[i].descr + ',';
        }
      }

      $('#valor').html(this.valore);
      $('#label').html(this.label);
    });

  }

}

// Objeto.
var obj = new json();
obj.resgatarValores();
```

**Estou querendo pegar os valores das divs e jogar nas variaves "data" e "labels" mais quando mando pegar o valor da div não aprarece nada. Mandei mostrar com alert() mais a caixa vem vazia**

```js
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {

            var data     = [document.getElementById('valor').value];
            var tooltips = [];
            //[2.59,2.60,2.40,2.67,1.78];
   
            // Create the tooltips
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=1) {
                tooltips[i] = '1 USD = ' + String(data[i] + ' Reais')
            }

            var line = new RGraph.Line({
                id: 'cvs',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    tooltips: {
                        self: tooltips,
                        highlight: false
                    },
                    colors: ['#058DC7'],
                    filled: true,
                    fillstyle: 'rgba(229,243,249,0.5)',
                    tickmarks: 'filledcircle',
                    background: {
                        grid: {
                            vlines: false,
                            border: false,
                            autofit: {
                                numhlines: 10
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    linewidth: 3,
                    gutter: {
                        left: 50,
                        right: 20
                    },
                    numxticks: 0,
                    ylabels: {
                        count: 5
                    },
                    axis: {
                        color: '#aaa'
                    },
                    text: {
                        color: '#aaa'
                    },
                    labels: ['21/01','22/01','23/01','24/01','25/01']
                }
            })
            
            RGraph.ISOLD ? line.draw() : line.trace2();
            
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    
    <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>
    <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js" ></script>
    <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.tooltips.js" ></script>
    <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.line.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2", {uncompressed:true});
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="json.class.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../excanvas/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    
    <p style="margin-left:50em;"><title>Cotação USD x BRL</title></p>
    
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta name="Descrição" content="Cotação do Dolar de Acordo com o Real" />
     
</head>
<body>

    <h2></h2>

    <canvas id="cvs" width="900" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>
    
  
 <div id="valor"></div>
 <div id="label"></div>
  
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta é a quarta pergunta sobre este assunto. Nó queremos ajudar mas tens de mostrar o código todo que tens e ou um exemplo live do problema. Senão fica dificil ajudar e vão-se acumulando perguntas que não levam a resposta/solução.

Comment: @Sergio todo código que tenho disponivel está acima

Comment: E esse JavaScript com a Classe para chamar o Json está num ficheiro à parte?

Comment: `<div>` não tem `value`, tem `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Sergio sim são 2 arquivos que tenho e postei aki o que pucha os resultados está em cima ele manda pra div do arquivo html que forma o gráfico.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu já tentei colocar com innerHTML mais também não mostrou os dados.

Comment: Amigo sua variável `data` é populada antes da função `resgatarValores` terminar sua requisição. Pense comigo é uma requisição Web. Ela pode durar um tempo variável enquanto `document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML` deve ser executada bem antes da resposta da requisição não retornando dado algum. Tente executar o código dentro do `$(document).ready(function ()` depois de receber seu JSON e informe se deu diferença.